# what does 'resolution' mean in embedded system?

Tags: embedded

I'm taking embedded system class and I keep seeing this word being used as a clock period. But sometimes, it acts differently to clock period. It's definitely not a graphics screen resolution. What's the exact definition in terms of embedded system?

Comment: This is entirely too broad. In embedded systems, "resolution" could mean clock resolution, timer resolution, ADC resolution, integer resolution, floating point resolution, screen resolution etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clock resolution is the smallest unit of time it can measure. For example, a clock with a rate of 1hz has a resolution of 1s. One with a rate of 60hz has a resolution of 16.6 repeating ms.

Desired unit in seconds/clock rate per second = resolution

1000ms/60 hz = 16.6 repeating ms

Answer (score 0):

The term has a general meaning relating to granularity or minimum increment that applies to time as well as images and displays.

In the case of a clock signal there are a number of terms relating to resolution that are probably less ambiguous such as period, frequency, or granularity.